# Fetching Duplicate data during development from list sharepoint hosted app

Tags: javascript

I am working in SharePoint hosted app. All the data stored in a list. When I am fetching the data, In my application is fetching duplicate data from the list. One record is showing four times. Previously it was working fine. My code is correct. I am using rest API. One URL is fetching same record four times.

Comment: As I understand You need to remove your duplicates. But without look at your code we can't give you a solution. Please add your code and show us what you reserved.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . issue was related to script i was calling the same script more that one.

Answer (score 0):

i was calling the same script more that one . that's why i was getting multiple records because every time rest API will be execute it will bind the data into data-table.